# How to find out in which element the item is placed after drag and drop in WPF

Tags: wpf

How can I know in which element drag and drop element is placed? For example I have 3 buttons named Button1, Button2, Button3. Drag a treeview item and drop it into one of the 3 buttons. How can I find out in which button it is placed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button control has an OnDrop method, and an associated Drop event. You just need to hook up the event for each button.

[Drop Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.drop.aspx)